# How to find modulo using Euler theorem?

Tags: number-theory, discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic, prime-factorization, totient-function

I don't know how that's possible using phi, the question starts with this one:

> a) Decompose 870 in prime factors and compute, ϕ(870)

I know how to resolve this, first 870 = 2*3*5*29 and ϕ(870)= 224

Now this is the question I don't know how to resolve:

> b) Compute 77^225 modulo 870 [**Using a)**] <--- The above question

870 isn't even a prime number.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

Use euler's theorem. If $(a,n)=1$, then
$$
a^{\varphi(n)}\equiv1\pmod{n}
$$
Since $77$ and $870$ are coprime (their prime factorizations have no prime in common)
$$
77^{225}
\equiv
77^{224}\times77\equiv1\times77\equiv77\pmod{870}
$$